# Creating a block bootstrap : How do I store output from a repeat function so I can reuse the code

Tags: r

I am trying to create a block bootstrap function that I can apply it to different machine learning problems.
To do so, I used a repeat function to get different blocks and compiled them into a single vector in the function loop. Here is my code :

```
#y is a the data Im creating the block bootstrap from , size is the length of each block

Blockboot <- function(y , size){
  output <- c()
  repeat{
    startind <- sample(length(y)- size + 1 , 1)
    block <- seq(from = startind , to = startind + size -1)
    output <- c(output , block)
    if(length(output)>=length(y)){
      print(output);
      break
    }
  }
}

#I ran the following to get a printed output
x = seq(500)
Blockboot(x , 4)
```

The function runs and is able to print my output, however, my output is not saved as a vector to the global environment. How do I modify my function such that the output is saved into the environment?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add `return(output)` within your `if` statement. You also need to assign the function result to a vector.

```
#y is a the data Im creating the block bootstrap from , size is the length of each block

Blockboot <- function(y , size){
  output <- c()
  repeat{
    startind <- sample(length(y)- size + 1 , 1)
    block <- seq(from = startind , to = startind + size -1)
    output <- c(output , block)
    if(length(output)>=length(y)){
      print(output)
      return(output)
      break
    }
  }
}

#I ran the following to get a printed output
x = seq(500)
your_result <- Blockboot(x , 4)
your_result # <- this is your global variable
```